# Find all solutions $z\in \mathbb C$ for the following equation: $z^2 +3\bar{z} -2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The question is

> Find all solutions $z\in \mathbb C$ for the following equation: $z^2 +3\bar{z} -2=0$

I have attempted numerous methods of approaching this question, from trying to substitute $x+iy$ and $x-iy$ respectively, in addition to substituting $z^2$ for $z\bar z$, but with no luck. I would really appreciate if you were able to provide some direction so I know where to start. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: There is an almost identical question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066628/quadratic-with-complex-solutions-including-a-conjugate-z-within-equation-how-to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in $x+iy$ for $z$ seems to be a good idea actually. You get
$$(x^2-y^2+3x-2)+i(2xy-3y)=0$$
For a complex number to be zero both the real and the imaginary part have to be zero, so we get $2xy=3y$ and $x^2-y^2+3x-2=0$. The first equation is easy for $y \neq 0$. Then we get $x=1.5$ and from there we can conclude $y= \pm \sqrt{4.75}$ with the second equation.

If $y=0$ the second equation is a quadratic in $x$ with two solutions that can easily be calculated with the quadratic formula. All in all we will have four solutions: $$(1.5, \sqrt{4.75}), (1.5, -\sqrt{4.75}), (..., 0), (..., 0)$$

Answer (score 1):

No need for real and imaginary parts here.

From $z^2 +3\bar z = 2$ we have  $\overline{z^2 +3\bar z} = \bar 2$.  Now $\overline{z^2 +3\bar z}= \bar z^2+3z$.
Hence we have
$$\begin{align}
z^2 +3\bar z &= 2\\
\bar z^2+3 z &=2
\end{align}
$$

Subtracting gives
$$(z-\bar z)(z+\bar z-3)=0,$$
that is $z=\bar z$ (hence $z$ is real in this case) or $\bar z =3-z$.  Both lead to quadratic equation: the first has two real solutions, the latter two complex solutions.

Comment: If you start out by assuming z is real (which you do when asserting that $z^2+ 3\overline z= 2$ is the same as $z^2+ 3z= 2$) then of course you are going to conclude that z is real!

Comment: I don't take that assumption: I just took the conjugation on both sides of the equation: from $z^2 +\bar z = 2$ I get $\overline{z^2 +\bar z} = \bar 2$.  Now $\overline{z^2 +\bar z}= \bar z^2+z$.