# quadratic with complex solutions including a conjugate z within equation how to solve?

Tags: complex-numbers

$z^2+3\bar{z}+2=0$
, this is my question I solved the real roots of -1 and -2 but am not sure how to compute these into a complex solution in wolfram alpha the solutions were1/2 (3 - i sqrt(35)) and 1/2 (3 + i sqrt(35)) which is where I am confused how to reach , thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$z = x+iy$.

Express the equation as two equations, one representing the real portion and one representing the imaginary portion.  Then, you will have two equations in the two unknowns, $x$ and $y$.

Focus on the equation representing the imaginary portion first.  You should see two cases to explore.  Explore them separately.